# Type '{ src: String; }' is not assignable to type 'SVGProps<SVGImageElement>

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am getting the following error when I do something like this

```
import React from 'react'
import "./../../styles/container.scss"
import './../../styles/common.scss'

interface containerProps {
  icon: String,
  heading: String,
  para: String, 
}


export const IconRowContainer = ({heading, para, icon}: containerProps) => {
  return (
    <div className="icon-row-container-main-div">
      <image src={icon} />
      <div>
        <h2 className="secondary-heading icon-row-container-heading"> {heading} </h2>
        <p className="para icon-row-container-para"> {para}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Error

> Type '{ src: String; }' is not assignable to type
>   'SVGProps'.   Property 'src' does not exist on type
>   'SVGProps'

Any idea what I could be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 20):

Use `<img src={icon} />` instead of `<image src={icon} />`

Comment: Should be a comment really.

Answer (score 4):

All primitive types should be **lowercased** and image tag isn't available in **native HTML tags** list you have to use **img** instead.

```js
import React from 'react'
import "./../../styles/container.scss"
import './../../styles/common.scss'

interface containerProps {
  icon: string,
  heading: string,
  para: string, 
}


export const IconRowContainer: React.FC<containerProps> = ({heading, para, icon}) => {
  return (
    <div className="icon-row-container-main-div">
      <img src={icon} />
      <div>
        <h2 className="secondary-heading icon-row-container-heading"> {heading} </h2>
        <p className="para icon-row-container-para"> {para}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was running into the issue in next.js and this what was happening is that `import image from "next/image` had `image` as lowercase so it should have been `import Image from "next/image"` and using the `<Image/>` as uppercase too